Craig interpolants for Linear Temporal Logic: finding one when they exist
It is known that Linear Temporal Logic (LTL) does not support Craig's theorem, so there are formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ where $\phi\to\psi$ holds but an interpolant does not exist.
In principle, there may be fragments of LTL supporting interpolation, a trivial special case being the propositional fragment where the original Craig's theorem applies.
However, I've found some literature about the topic and it seems there are not useful proper fragments of LTL supporting interpolation apart from the one with only the tomorrow operator which is just syntactic-sugar on top of propositional logic and is not really interesting.
So I cannot have guarantees that an interpolant exists between $\phi$ and $\psi$, however is there an algorithmic way to compute an interpolant if it exists?
I'm interested both in LTL on infinite and finite words, if it makes any difference (btw, I don't know if everything above holds for finite words as well: is it true that LTL on finite words does not support interpolants neither?)

Decidability of Craig Interpolant Existence for LTL over finite words follows from:
[1] K. Henkell. 1988. Pointlike sets: The finest aperiodic cover of a finite semigroup. Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra
55, 1-2 (1988), 85–126.
[2] K. Henkell, J. Rhodes, and B. Steinberg. 2010. Aperiodic pointlikes and beyond. International Journal of Algebra and
Computation 20, 2 (2010), 287–305,
while the case of omega-word is treated in:
[3]  Thomas Place and Marc Zeitoun. 2016. Separating regular languages with first-order logic. Logical Methods in Computer Science 12, 1:5 (2016), 1–30
These results are formulated in terms of the separability problem but CIP Existence and separability are known to be equivalent.
You may also be interested in the following paper:
[4] Jean Christoph Jung, Jedrzej Kolodziejski:
Modal Separability of Fixpoint Formulae. Description Logics 2024

Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!
